# PHP file isn't outputing to local browser, just showing code

Tags: php, file, settings, reset, file-association

Originally, I would select my php files and it would open the site on my local browser, I accidently opened it to notepad and now it will only open the code to editors. Does anyone know how to change the file setting back to when it would execute in the local browser? Ive tried resetting the filetype associations and resetting the file extension settings in the registry editor. I am currently using Windows 11

Comment: You should share what operating system you are using

Comment: Sorry about that , I just updated the post to include I am on Windows 11

Comment: Try these. I like to use Right click, open with, select new app, browse for the app, check bottom box to use that app in the future https://windowsreport.com/windows-11-remove-file-association/

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a servlet like wamp or xampp you cannot process the php file on localhost.As long as the files have a php extension and are in the target folder of the servlet, while the servlet is active (example: if there is an index.php in the www folder in wamp. It will work if you type localhost/index.php in the browser.) your php files will work.

Comment: So my question is a little hard to understand and a bit confusing. The issue isn't regarding my Xampp. The issue is, when I would originally double click a php file, it would open the local browser and execute the website regarding the php file. One day, while double clicking a php file, I selected the option of opening it with a text editor. So now everytime I select a php file it opens an editor instead of opening the site on a local web browser. I am trying to figure out how to re associate my php files with opening and executing the website instead of going to a text editor.